# algorithm to convert technical specification into object model

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have detailed specification of what should my program take as input, and give as output.

How to convert this specification into classes/methods/properties?

I used such algorithm:

1. Take specification, plus data flow model based on it
2. Extract nouns from them (most frequently used or important from your point of view)
3. Use nouns from 2 as classes to model your system, if all looks good - done, else step back to 2 or 1.

Is any more formal algorithms for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is any one answer, but rather many (likely opinionated) answers.

What you're talking about might generally fall under [Software Development Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) or Design Methodologies, such as [Domain-driven_design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).  The space is pretty large, and, Wikipedia has a good (but more than likely incomplete) ontology around software development, and, you may find what you're looking for therein or at least the terminology of some of what your scoping.  DDD talks about establishing a vocabulary within a context, and also focuses on identifying persistent state and linkages (external and internal).  DDD establishes a context for the development of services.  (There's almost always another larger context, though!)

Others recommend processes like Test Driven Development, where use cases and other scenarios are developed as tests, first, then software developed to resolve the new failing tests.

Some like [Business Process Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modeling), where the idea is to decompose the problem into processes, which often look like flowcharts.  I don't care for it as I prefer the notion of services (which focus more on externally visible interfaces) as an abstraction over the notion of processes, which tend to put focus too much on internal implementation detail.

Our job as programmers is to realize a domain-oriented solution using our toolbox of programming languages and frameworks.  Essentially we're creating a live mapping (that includes behaviors) between the business domain and the information technology domain that computers more naturally operate on.

You're on the right track by starting with a domain-oriented concepts (the nouns), and translating them IT concepts.  The abstractions you choose are significant choices in the design process.  (Verbs, of course, may translate into methods or functions.)

I noticed that your approach doesn't incorporate recursive decomposition.  Sometimes a given entity is sufficiently complex that it is impractical to implement directly.  So, some entities are decomposed into a number of smaller ones, which may end up being classes, unless they decompose as well.  Classes aren't the only abstraction, for one, we also have namespaces that help organize classes, so perhaps a concept that decomposes into several classes gets its own namespace.

Refactoring is also a significant approach to the iterative software development process.  We start, then later find room for improvement of the existing functionality, and so change/improve the design independently of adding new features.

Scrum, Agile, lean, other approaches should be considered as well.

You described a program as taking input and producing output. Many programs need to live longer than a single run, supporting multiple users, for example.  Many programs these days also demand persistent state, which may mean using a database, so sometimes the nouns translate into relational entities as well.

There are also lots of choices of technologies to consider.  Databases, ORM frameworks, UI frameworks, programming languages, etc..

Further, there are methodologies around getting to a better initial picture, which goes to improving the specification you might start with as input to your iterative algorithm.  Perhaps DDD might help there as well, in addition to the more general field of requirements gathering.

I also am a big fan of layering.  Layering is a form of modularity, the idea of which is to present a consistent set of abstractions for the next layer up to use.  That next layer up should use only the immediate layer below it, and especially nothing further below.  That next layer up then does the same thing (present a consistent set of abstractions) for its superior layer.  This organizational mechanism helps with very large code bases.

Of course, many of these software development approaches can be used in conjunction.  See also [other methodologies](http://www.slideshare.net/anniyappa/software-design-methodologies)